# Return the count of courses using satisfies contains XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery, contains, xquery-3.0

I have been struggling to return the count of courses from [this XML file](https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/courses-noID.xml) that contain "Cross-listed" as their description. The problem I encounter is because I am using for, it iterates and gives me "1 1" instead of "2". When I try using let instead I get 13 which means it counts all without condition even when I point return count($c["Cross-listed"]. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance

```
for $c in doc("courses.xml")//Department/Course
where some $desc in $c/Description
satisfies contains($desc, "Cross-listed")
return count($c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I encounter is because I am using for

You are quite correct. You don't need to process items individually in order to count them.

You've made things much too difficult. You want

```
count(doc("courses.xml")//Department/Course[Description[contains(., "Cross-listed"]])
```

The key thing here is: you want a count, so call the `count()` function, and give it an argument which selects the set of things you want to include in the count.

Comment: I didn't know that you can use the contains function in XPath like that. That makes it super simple, but what if I wanted to solve it using where and satisfies contains, is it still possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Pitagora, as Michael said: "call the count() function, and give it an argument which selects the set of things you want to include", so if you want to use for `for` expression you need to call `count` on the complete expression `count(for $c in doc("courses.xml")//Department/Course where ... return $c)`